# Visual studio displaying massive syntax errors after update

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I updated Visual Studio 2019 to its latest version as of now. After the update, I opened a previous project which was compiled & run perfectly before the update, but when I built it, there is a massive list of syntax errors of which some say declaration missing etc. I have been looking for a solution for this but the problem doesn't seem to go away. SS attached:
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbF0m.jpg)

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct time {
    long hour;
    long minute;
    long seconds;
};
time Time1(time &a){
    if (a.minute >= 60 && a.seconds >= 60){
        a.minute += a.seconds / 60;
        a.hour += a.minute / 60;
        a.minute %= 60;
        a.seconds %= 60;
    }

    cout << "Time 1 is: " << a.hour << ":" << a.minute << ":" << a.seconds << endl;
    return a;
}
time Time2(time &b){

    if (b.minute >= 60 && b.seconds >= 60){
        b.minute += b.seconds / 60;
        b.hour += b.minute / 60;
        b.minute %= 60;
        b.seconds %= 60;
    }
    
    cout << "Time 2 is: " << b.hour << ":" << b.minute << ":" << b.seconds << endl;
    return b;

}
void main(){
    time t1;
    time t2;
    time t3;
    cout << "Enter hours: ";
    cin >> t1.hour;
    cout << "Enter minutes: ";
    cin >> t1.minute;
    cout << "Enter seconds: ";
    cin >> t1.seconds;
    Time1(t1);
    cout << "Enter hours: ";
    cin >> t2.hour;
    cout << "Enter minutes: ";
    cin >> t2.minute;
    cout << "Enter seconds: ";
    cin >> t2.seconds;
    Time2(t2);
    cout << "Adding Time 1 and Time 2 = ";
    t3.hour = t1.hour + t2.hour;
    t3.minute = t1.minute + t2.minute;
    t3.seconds = t1.seconds + t2.seconds;
    if (t3.seconds >= 60 && t3.minute >= 60){
        t3.minute += t3.seconds / 60;
        t3.hour += t3.minute / 60;
        t3.minute %= 60;
        t3.seconds %= 60;
    }
    cout << t3.hour << ":" << t3.minute << ":" << t3.seconds << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Errors:

```
   Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Source.cpp
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(9,11): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(9,1): error C2365: 'time': redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\time.h(532): message : see declaration of 'time'
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(9,6): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'Time1'
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(10,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(10,1): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(24,11): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(24,1): error C2365: 'time': redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\time.h(532): message : see declaration of 'time'
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(24,6): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'Time2'
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(25,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(25,1): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(40,1): warning C4326: return type of 'main' should be 'int' instead of 'void'
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(41,10): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 't1'
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(41,5): warning C4551: function call missing argument list
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(41,10): error C2065: 't1': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(42,10): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 't2'
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(42,5): warning C4551: function call missing argument list
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(42,10): error C2065: 't2': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(43,10): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 't3'
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(43,5): warning C4551: function call missing argument list
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(43,10): error C2065: 't3': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(45,12): error C2065: 't1': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(47,12): error C2065: 't1': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(49,12): error C2065: 't1': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(50,11): error C2065: 't1': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(50,5): error C3861: 'Time1': identifier not found
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(52,12): error C2065: 't2': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(54,12): error C2065: 't2': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(56,12): error C2065: 't2': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(57,11): error C2065: 't2': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(57,5): error C3861: 'Time2': identifier not found
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(59,5): error C2065: 't3': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(59,15): error C2065: 't1': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(59,25): error C2065: 't2': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(60,5): error C2065: 't3': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(60,17): error C2065: 't1': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(60,29): error C2065: 't2': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(61,5): error C2065: 't3': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(61,18): error C2065: 't1': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(61,31): error C2065: 't2': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(62,9): error C2065: 't3': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(62,29): error C2065: 't3': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(64,9): error C2065: 't3': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(64,22): error C2065: 't3': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(65,9): error C2065: 't3': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(65,20): error C2065: 't3': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(66,9): error C2065: 't3': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(67,9): error C2065: 't3': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(69,13): error C2065: 't3': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(69,31): error C2065: 't3': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\CM-Ajk\source\repos\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION\Source.cpp(69,51): error C2065: 't3': undeclared identifier
1>Done building project "ADDITION OF TIMES USING STRUCTURE FUNCTION.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Please copy/paste the actual errors from the Output window (*not* the Error List window), starting with the first ones, and the relevant code that triggers them.

Comment: Did you do a Clean and Rebuild of the project?

Comment: Isn't there a std::time() this may be another conflict with `using namespace std;` although the error messages I am not sure.

Comment: I have added the code, the errors from the output window were too long and could not be formatted. @dxiv

Comment: try commenting out `using namespace std;` and see if the errors about `time` goes away.  I expect errors about `cout` and `cin` to be added but those are easily fixable.

Comment: I have done that but didn't make any difference @1201ProgramAlarm

Comment: @Emad Just copy/paste the errors inside a `\`\`\` ... \`\`\`` code block. What you show is the trailing end of the Error List. What you should be looking at, instead, is the *first* error(s) in the Output window.

Comment: That is very important. The Errors List is not in file order. And the Output Tab often has a more verbose error message.

Comment: @drescherjm I tried it, the errors still remain except cout and cin errors are added.

Comment: I have added the error list from output window now.

Comment: This is quite odd. I see that you only include iostream so there is not likely a #define causing this.

Comment: @Emad `Source.cpp(9,1): error C2365: 'time': redefinition; previous definition was 'function'`. Don't use library names for your types.

Comment: That error suggests the bug is caused by `using namespace std;`

Comment: I updated the errors as I had commented the using namespace std; previously. But the point is, the code is untouched before and after the update. Before updating, it compiled & run, but now it does not.

Comment: An update will break code that has conflicts like this.

Comment: @Emad It's good practice to define your types in your own namespace. Especially when using names known to conflict with library definitions.

Comment: @dxiv I changed the structure "struct time" name and the code has now compiled & run successfully. Thanks.